# How to get an array of all keys by value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

How do I turn this array:

```
$details = ["Dog" => "Natahlia", "Cat" => "Ryan", "Bird" => "Natahlia"];
```

Into this(desired output):

```
$details = [["Natahlia"=>["Dog","Bird"], "Ryan"=>"Cat"];
```

Having some trouble since my code concatenates the values or either overwrites it.

```
$arr = array();
foreach($details as $key => $value){
   if(array_key_exists($value,$arr)){
      //this part i dont know what to do since += wont do it since it's a string and .= concatenates it
      $arr[$value] = $key;
   } else {
      $arr[$value] = $key;
   }
}
return $arr;
```

Comment: Is it literally just those values you want and always want to adjust? If so then just manually set the array. I guess not tho, and that means you need to explain what determines when to create the structure you require

Comment: The example array you gave isn't a valid array - it's hard to know what you want exactly outside those exact values

Comment: are your array formatting is right using the square brackets i think it's wrong

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi That was LihO's edit that made it incorrect again.

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi `[]` is the exact same as `array()`

Comment: I thought at start point `array()` is good practice.

Comment: @KDOT See the revision history, it was `array[`

Comment: @Andreas it possibly was but we don't write code from the 19th Century so it doesn't really matter, `$arr = [];` is the same as `$arr = array();`. His comment said it was wrong so I informed him its the same as writing `array()`.

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi 'Best practice' does not cause errors but, rightfully, it is good to use it

Comment: @KDOT What does the 19th century have to do with a syntax error?  `array[` is not a valid syntax.

Comment: OK OK Fellows I got Updated. :)  hahaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to loop the full array.
You only need to loop the unique names and do an array_intersect with that name.
The array_intersect will return matching names with the keys as the animal, so array_keys that and you get what you expect.
This only loops the unique names, so it may be faster than looping the full array.

```
$details = ["Dog" => "Natahlia", "Cat" => "Ryan", "Bird" => "Natahlia"];


foreach(array_unique($details) as $name){
    $new[$name] = array_keys(array_intersect($details, [$name]));
}
var_dump($new);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
     ["Natahlia"] => array(2) {
            [0] => "Dog"
            [1] => "Bird"
    }
    ["Ryan"] => array(1) {
            [0] => "Cat"
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/paYRJ

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi Thank you. But to be honest I know for sure this will not be the fastest method always. Only if the array is large and pet owners have very limited imagination will this outperform looping the full array. I think. Not sure though. But I doubt it will be faster with less than say 100-200 items.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$details = ["Dog" => "Natahlia", "Cat" => "Ryan", "Bird" => "Natahlia"];

foreach($details as $animal => $name)
    $result[$name][] = $animal;

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
'Natahlia' => 
array (
    0 => 'Dog',
    1 => 'Bird',
),
'Ryan' => 
array (
    0 => 'Cat',
),
)
```